# mingw boost library not working

Tags: boost, cmake, mingw, clion

I am trying to make the boost library work with CMake but I get some weird error messages.
I am using Stephan T. Lavavej`s mingw version which comes with boost-library.

My CMake file looks like the following :

```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(untitled)

set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR C:/MinGW/include)
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR C:/MinGW/lib)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})



set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Ofast -msse -msse2 -msse3  -march=znver1 -fno-use-linker-plugin -flto")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -static-libstdc++ ")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp HexBoard.cpp HexBoard.h TreeNode.cpp TreeNode.h)
add_executable(untitled ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

and I get the following error messages:

```
> CMake Warning at C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/CLion
> 2016.3.5/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:743 (message):   Imported targets not available for Boost version 106300
> Call Stack (most recent call first):   C:/Program Files
> (x86)/JetBrains/CLion
> 2016.3.5/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:842 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)   C:/Program Files
> (x86)/JetBrains/CLion
> 2016.3.5/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1395 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)   CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)
> 
> 
> CMake Warning at C:/Program Files (x86)/JetBrains/CLion
> 2016.3.5/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:743 (message):   Imported targets not available for Boost version 106300
> Call Stack (most recent call first):   C:/Program Files
> (x86)/JetBrains/CLion
> 2016.3.5/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:842 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)   C:/Program Files
> (x86)/JetBrains/CLion
> 2016.3.5/bin/cmake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1395 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)   CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)
```

How can I make the boost library work under mingw64 ?

Would appreciate any help

Comment: There is **no error** in the log you show, only *warnings*. The warnings don't prevent things to work. If you are curious what these warnings means and how to eliminate them, then google for "Imported targets not available for Boost version".

Comment: By the way, logs become readable if *formatted as a code*. *Citation* formatting is not good here.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the same setup, my **make** file looks like yours.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14") 

set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR c:/mingw/include/)
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR c:/mingw/lib/)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

I have also added the MINGW paths to my systems environment user variables.
[image]